# Run script without ./ before the name

Tags: bash, compiling, executable

I am running a quite complicated script which changes directories and runs many other commands. All these commands are run using 'scriptname', which works fine when I execute the main script from my terminal. However, sometimes I have to ssh into a server and run the main script from there, it fails as there isn't a ./ before each command.

I'd rather not go through all the scripts and executables and add a ./ to the commands, so is there another way to solve this problem?

Comment: Just make sure "current directory" is in your path: http://superuser.com/questions/350844/how-to-permanently-add-current-directory-to-path-in-linux

Comment: I am not sure I completely agree with with adding the current directory, especially if that happens in the form of `$PATH:.`, because it poses a security risk ... more so when you are `root`. But having a dedicated script path and adding that should be fine if the permissions for that path are tight.

Comment: @DigitalChris, *don't ever* do that, it opens you to a nasty security problem (just add an executable called, e.g. `sl` to `/tmp` or somewhere else writable by you, and wait until an unsuspecting victim fat-fingers `ls(1)` as `sl`...)

Comment: @vonbrand: [`sl`](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/displays-animations-when-accidentally-you-type-sl-instead-of-ls.html), you say?  https://github.com/mtoyoda/sl

Comment: @RocketHazmat replace by whatever typo of a common command you like

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are ways to change this behavior including adding `./` to your PATH environment variable, but this introduces a serious security risk to your environment. The way your scripts are written is really wrong and the correct solution is to go through all of them and fix the way local scripts are called. This is the only proper fix that will not introduce extra problems down the road and create security issues for you. I know it's not what you *wanted* to hear, but bite the bullet and do it right.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Since I'm using university machines, I guess it's better to be safe than sorry, so I'll amend the scripts (and curse the person who wrote them!)

Comment: @user72404: that's how developers do. Curse them predecessors. Curse them! ;)

Answer (score 1):

if your scripts happen to be under /opt/housekeeping/bin, i suggest you add

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/housekeeping/bin
```

to your .bash_profile or .profile  or whatever your login script you use & ensure 755 permission is set as well on those scripts.

Comment: Why not `~/.local/bin`, or even `~/bin`

Comment: i do not understand Wilf, can you enlighten me

Answer (score -1):

you can create an alias for your script:

```
alias scriptfile="./scriptfile"
```

Comment: I think the issue is he's calling a bunch of commands/scripts from within that depend on his `$PATH` being a certain way, so this won't help with those.

Comment: i think you thinking that is no reason to downvote.

Comment: or upvote yourself thinking that <.<

Comment: I was not the one to DV this, if I did I would've left a comment as to why.

Comment: @user72461 you can't upvote your own comments...